# How can i trim spaces in object.values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

my `object.values(article.data)` returns

```
[' This is ']
['is ']
['a']
['sentence ']
```

how can i trim and remove the spaces so it becomes

```
['Thisis']
['is']
['a']
['sentence']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you want to update the object, you need to iterate over the object entries and assign the updated values to each of the object keys. Since your object values are arrays, you need to iterate over each of the values within those arrays, replacing all spaces in them with an empty string.

```js
let obj = {
  'k1': [' This is '],
  'k2': ['is '],
  'k3': ['a'],
  'k4': ['sentence ']
}

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  obj[key] = value.map(v => v.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
}

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

considering your array is named ar

```
ar.map(s => s.trim());
```

it should return the array trimmed

Comment: That's usually a nice way to do this, but look at the first example — they want to remove *all* the spaces.

Comment: Tips: First understand what OP wants  then answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `map` you can achive it by trimming it:

```js
var data=[['    This is    '],['is '],['a '],['   sentence']];
var result = data.map(val=>[val[0].trim()]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i am accepting the answer from nick

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in a cleaner way

```js
let obj = {
  'k1': [' This is '],
  'k2': ['is '],
  'k3': ['a'],
  'k4': ['sentence ']
}


const result = Object.values(obj).map(values => values.map(value => value.replace(/\s/g, '')));

console.log(result)
```